# Why do I get a TopologyClosed error during cleanup of my tests?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, jestjs

I'm running some integration tests against MongoDB sitting with a local docker image. I've got some teardown code within Jest to ensure that I cleanup any connections to MongoDB:

```
import { client } from "../lib/common/mongodb";

module.exports = async function () {
    await client.close();
};
```

This looks pretty straight forward, but everyime I call `client.close()` I get the following error:

```
/home/ian/src/my-proj/node_modules/mongodb/lib/sdam/topology.js:217
                drainWaitQueue(this[kWaitQueue], new error_1.MongoTopologyClosedError());
                                                 ^

MongoTopologyClosedError: Topology is closed
    at /home/ian/src/my-proj/node_modules/mongodb/src/sdam/topology.ts:493:46 {
  [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(0) {}
}

Node.js v20.2.0
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

In this case the `client` in a singleton instance of Mongo client;

```
let client;
let clientPromise;

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development" || process.env.NODE_ENV === "test") {
  // In development mode, use a global variable so that the value
  // is preserved across module reloads caused by HMR (Hot Module Replacement).
  let globalWithMongo = global;

  const uri = MONGO_SERVER_URL.replace("<username>", MONGO_USERNAME).replace("<password>", MONGO_PASSWORD);

  if (!globalWithMongo._mongoClientPromise) {
    client = new MongoClient(uri, options);
    globalWithMongo._mongoClientPromise = client.connect();
  }

  clientPromise = globalWithMongo._mongoClientPromise;
} else {
  // In production mode, it's best to not use a global variable.
  client = new MongoClient(uri, options);
  clientPromise = client.connect();
}

// Export a module-scoped MongoClient promise. By doing this in a
// separate module, the client can be shared across functions.
export default clientPromise;

export { client };
```

Does anyone know why I might be getting this error and how to debug it to ensure my tests exit cleanly? I've had to add the following hack to workaround it (as client.close doesn't thrown a catchable exception).

```
import { client } from "../lib/common/mongodb";

module.exports = async function () {
    process.on('unhandledRejection', (e) => {
        console.log("This is a hack, to deal with MongoDB not shutting down properly. It does not interfere with Jest test failures");
        process.exit(0);
    });

    await client.close();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [the docs](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/4.6/classes/MongoTopologyClosedError.html), the error indicates you are attempting to run a query against an unavailable connection.

This can be due to the use of a single DB connection.

A solution:

Use a global Jest teardown and setup to open and close the DB connection.

This code tests if the database is currently connected before attempting to close the connection.

```js
const { client } = require("../lib/common/mongodb");

beforeAll(async () => {
    // Set up any necessary resources before running tests
    await client.connect();
});

afterAll(async () => {
    // Teardown and clean up resources after running tests
    if (client.isConnected()) {
        await client.close();
    }
});
```